# After upgrading environment to Ruby 3.0.1, my app continues to use 2.6.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I initially created my environment will ruby 2.6.3 via the tutorial I was following and the practice app. I started building my own custom app and when I realized via Heroku that I wasn't using the most current version of Ruby (3.0.1). So I upgraded the root environment, but my app continues to use 2.6.3 even though I updated the Gem File.. I keep getting this message *Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.1* I can fix this temporarily by running rvm use 3.0.1, but I have to do this every time I start a new terminal.

Somewhere online someone said to run bundle env to get the ruby version and path. so here is that information

```
Bundler             2.2.17
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-linux
Ruby                2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
  Full Path         /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /etc
RubyGems            3.0.3
  Gem Home          /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3
  Gem Path          /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  User Home         /home/ubuntu
  User Path         /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  Bin Dir           /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin
Tools               
  Git               2.17.1
  RVM               1.29.12-next (master)
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.5)
```

Can't seem to find a clear answer on what to change to permanently have my app use 3.0.1.

Comment: Do you have an rvmrc file? What does "upgraded the root environment" mean? What commands are you actually running?

Comment: If you specify the ruby version in your Gemfile e.g. `ruby '3.0.1'` or if you add a ".ruby-version" file to the root of the application and specify the version there, then rvm will recognize this and will change your ruby version every time you cd into the root of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add .ruby-version?

If not, add `.ruby-version`  file to under your project path and put it ruby version

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. There was a .ruby-version there and it was set to 2.6.3, I updated and it fixed the problem. Thanks!